# message compontent(s) on your Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

i need to insert two different message error in the save method. 
in my controller i done: 
two IF and everyone had :

1) `ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'MESSAGE ONE!!');`
and

2)`ApexPages.Message myMsg2 = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'MESSAGE TWO!!');`

In VisulaForce page :

```
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="xxxxx" rerender="msgs"/>
```

how can i rerendender msgs and msgs2???

Thank you and sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in the controller you have created your two errors 
You then need to add them onto the page

```
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg2);
```

In the Vf page make sure you have the msgs you are trying to re-render

```
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>

ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'MESSAGE ONE!!');

ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

ApexPages.Message myMsg2 = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'MESSAGE ONE!!');

ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg2);
```

Comment: yes i have id="msgs" i must add id="msgs2"?                                                                    i can't write re-render msgs and msgs2 like <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Salva e vai avanti" rerender="msgs", "msgs2", "msgs3"/>

Comment: MY controller is this:     ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Errore: È necessario Specificare la versione di JAVA!!');
                     
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message (ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Errore: È necessario Specificare la versione di JAVA!!'));
                   return null;

Comment: The line  rerender="msgs" is referring to a panel  inside the page, Not your controller.
So you are saying on save i want to reRender the panel with Id 'msgs'

Comment: Luci, What Tim is explaining is to show all messages that you may have added in your controller. <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/> here, msgs is the Id of this pageMessages component which will be rendered when you will click your save button. Do not confuse this with messages which you have defined in VF page (ApexPages.Message myMsg2). If you are using <apex:pageMessages> or <apex:messages> they will always pick up all messages at each point when they are rerendered. You can not cherry-pick messages you want to display.